# How to convert rgba to Hex from an array?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[snapshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRFV7.jpg) [A snapshot]   I'll retrieve the background color of one of seven days and convert to hex. The hours of the day select automatically at mid-night and highlighted with purple color. I'll select highlighted hours from the list of seven days. I ran an array and got this result one of the seven days- " rgb(92, 50, 150) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box "
 But my conversion is not running and throwing this error- 
No enum constant org.openqa.selenium.support.Colors.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 0) NONE REPEAT SCROLL 0% 0% / AUTO PADDING-BOX BORDER-BOX

Sunday: 







             Closed

      
      
    
                

    Monday: 







             12:00 pm
                             - 
                 8:00 pm

      
      
    
                

    Tuesday: 







             1:00 pm
                             - 
                 6:00 pm

      
      
    
                

    Wednesday: 







             10:00 am
                             - 
                 6:00 pm

      
      
    
                

    Thursday: 







             12:00 pm
                             - 
                 8:00 pm

      
      
    
                

    Friday: 







             10:00 am
                             - 
                 6:00 pm

      
      
    
                

    Saturday: 







             10:00 am
                             - 
                 5:00 pm

@Test (priority=3, description="Verify the date and Hours")
    public void today() throws InterruptedException {
        WebElement sunday =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='hours']/div/div/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRFV7.jpg)"));
        String sundayHrs =sunday.getCssValue("background");
        String selectSunday = Color.fromString(sundayHrs).asHex();
        WebElement monday = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='hours']/div/div/div/div[2]"));
        String mondayHrs =monday.getCssValue("background");
        String selectMonday = Color.fromString(mondayHrs).asHex();
        WebElement tuesday = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='hours']/div/div/div/div[3]"));
        String tuesdayHrs =tuesday.getCssValue("background");
        String selectTuesday = Color.fromString(tuesdayHrs).asHex();
        WebElement wednesday = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='hours']/div/div/div/div[4]"));
        String wednesdayHrs = wednesday.getCssValue("background");
        String selectWednesday = Color.fromString(wednesdayHrs).asHex();
        WebElement thursday =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='hours']/div/div/div/div[5]"));
        String thursdayHrs =thursday.getCssValue("background");
        String selectThursday = Color.fromString(thursdayHrs).asHex();
        WebElement friday =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='hours']/div/div/div/div[6]"));
        String fridayHrs= friday.getCssValue("background");
        String selectFriday = Color.fromString(fridayHrs).asHex();

```
    WebElement saturday =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='hours']/div/div/div/div[7]"));
    String saturdayHrs= saturday.getCssValue("background");
    String selectSaturday = Color.fromString(saturdayHrs).asHex();



    String [] selectDate = {selectSunday, selectMonday, selectTuesday, selectWednesday, selectThursday, selectFriday, selectSaturday};

    for (String dtColor:selectDate) {
        System.out.println(dtColor);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are trying to convert rgba to hex right ?

Comment: Yes I want to convert but from seven days i'll select one row

Comment: I posted solution if its not what your looking for please try to edit your question so I can understand what you are trying to do more. with some code examples

Comment: Post the relevant HTML. I doubt you even need to convert RGB at all... just look for the right class, etc. and you can do that in a locator.

Comment: I thought selario had that problem solved already!!

Comment: HI  All and @Omarito I added a little elaborated of my question looking still the solution, if possible please help me .

Answer (score 1):

There is many ways you can achieve this:
**First solution :**

```
String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x%02x", a, r, g, b);
```

**Second Solution :**

```
public int toHex(Color color) {
    String alpha = addPadding(Integer.toHexString(color.getAlpha()));
    String red = addPadding(Integer.toHexString(color.getRed()));
    String green = addPadding(Integer.toHexString(color.getGreen()));
    String blue = addPadding(Integer.toHexString(color.getBlue()));
    String hex = "0x" + alpha + red + green + blue;
    return Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
}

private static final String addPadding(String s) {
    return (s.length() == 1) ? "0" + s : s;
}
```

The first solution return hex string and the second return the hex represented by integer.

Answer (score 0):

Get it done fast using some bitwise operators. This can also be used to efficiently pack a 32 bit color.

```
String rgba2hex(int red, int green, int blue, int alpha) {
    return String.format("0x%08X", rgba(red, green, blue, alpha));
}

int rgba(int red, int green, int blue, int alpha) {
    int rgba = 0;
    rgba |= (alpha & 0xff) << 24;
    rgba |= (red & 0xff) << 16;
    rgba |= (green & 0xff) << 8;
    rgba |= (blue & 0xff);
    return rgba;
}

// reverse it
int[] rgba(int rgba) {
    int[] color = new int[4];
    color[4] = (rgba >> 24) & 0xff; // alpha
    color[1] = (rgba >> 16) & 0xff; // red
    color[2] = (rgba >> 8) & 0xff; // green
    color[3] = rgba & 0xff; // blue
    return color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `java.awt.Color` class, you can grab the rgb value.

```
String color2hex(Color color) {
    return String.format("#%08X", color.getRGB());
}
```